# Coverity - overrun of struct type

Tags: c, sockets

I am getting the following error through the coverity tool -

overrun-buffer-arg: Overrunning struct type in_addr of 4 bytes by passing it to a function which accesses it at byte offset 7 using argument "8UL".

sample code:

```
static u_long   addr;
static struct   sockaddr_in remote_server;
addr = inet_addr(remote_servername);
memcpy((char *) &remote_server.sin_addr, (char *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

In the last line, I am getting the above error.

Can someone through some light on, what's going wrong.

Please let me know, if you need any more information.

Comment: As the message says, a `u_long` is larger (8, apparently) than an `in_addr` which is only 4.

Comment: u_long is also 4 bytes size

Comment: I checked it in solaris 10 OS, It shows the size of u_long as 4

Comment: Coverity thinks it is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inet_addr() returns an in_addr_t, not an u_long.
struct sockaddr_in's sin_addr is a struct in_addr, which holds an in_addr_t s_addr.

This should do the trick:

```
static struct   sockaddr_in remote_server;
remote_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(remote_servername);
```

Comment: That really did the trick.  Though we have to check the return value of inet_addr(remote_servername) as a part of error checking.

Comment: If you have untrusted input, it is best not to use inet_addr() in the first place. Use inet_aton() instead:
    static struct   sockaddr_in remote_server;
    if (inet_aton(remote_servername, &remote_server.sin_addr)) {
      /* error */
    }

Answer (score 2):

Standard warning: Do not cast a pointer to/from `void *`.

For the message: read it carefully, it very well states the problem. Just a hint: Use proper types. You are apparently accessing a struct beyond its size. Which size doe u_long have actually?

`addr` should be serialized properly to an uint8_t[], respecting endianess. As you take `sizeof()` from the second argument, apparently the first argument is shorter.

Why do you not just assign, but use `memcpy()`? Check both have the same type.

Comment: thanks for replying. addr should have the datatype uint32_t right? I saw in the library, that remote_server.sin_addr.s_addr has the datatype uint32_t.

Comment: @GajendraBagali: Yes. And please do only use memcpy() to copy blocks of memory, e.g. structs or arrays. Do not copy scalars! Just use assignments instead. And: enable and follow warnings; I strongly recomend to have at least `-Wall -Wextra` enabled for gcc (for a different compiler choose someting similar)! The problem above ("truncation warning") might have not been reported without warnings enabled either. C is not typesafe in all aspects, but modern compilers warn about _many_(!) problems! (Note: VC is **not** a modern compiler in that sense)

Comment: Actually that is a legacy code. they used memcpy to assign scalars!. And yeah I try to have -Wall -Wextra enabled.

Comment: @GajendraBagali: I understand your problem. If they did, it is not just "legacy", but broken by design. Whoever did this should be ... well, you might have better ideas about that than me actually ;-)